# Append text to an HTML tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to use Jquery append to append text to a pre existing div element. I also want to have several element 'templates' and append more text into those elements (see snippet).

```js
var template = { template1: "<p class='someclass'></p>" },
    o = $('.divClass');
    o.append(template.template1); // Append text inside P tag
```

Comment: If the div has the id `example`, you can use `var element = document.getElementById("example");` and then just `element.innerHTML += "extra stuff";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
var template = { template1: $("<p class='someclass'></p>") },
    o = $('.divClass');

// Set template and append to container
var currentTemplate = template.template1;
o.append(currentTemplate);

// Get current text and append content to the end
var textNode = currentTemplate.text() + "Append Content";
currentTemplate.text(textNode);
```

Basically, I create the paragraph as it's own node rather than a text string so I had more flexibility with modifying the element. I would normally wait to append the element to my container until after I was done modifying it, but it will work either way.

You can also skip getting the current text if you don't need to append to what's there. Based on your other comments, you would loop through the bottom part, selecting each template and text node in your object and appending it to the container.

Comment: Thanks! That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your p element as a string, store it as an element. If it's already created, use getElementByID() or getElementByClassName(), if you are creating it now, use

```
var myPElement = document.createElement("p");
```

You can then freely change or append to the text that myPElement contains.

```
myPElement.innerHTML = "set text equal to this";
myPElement.innerHTML += "append this";
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm not sure how it translates well to what I'm looking for. Basically, I want to add a loop that adds multiple p elements with text taken from an object array. 

so it'd look something like:
 `for (index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
 o.append(template.template1)`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp Loop over objects in your array, for each one create a p element and a textElement. Then attach the textElement to the p element, and appendChild the p element to the parent container. They show how to do all of that in the link provided.